# Как рекурсивно удалить определённую папку в директории?

Tags: node.js, cmd

Есть очень много проектов с папками, которые нужно удалить(node_modules например).
Как с помощью node или cmd команды рекурсивно удалить определённую папку во всех вложенных папках?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Более простой и хороший вариант чем первый:

```
for /R "%WHERE%" %A in (.) do @if /i "%~nxA"=="%WHAT%" @rd /s /q "%A"
```

%WHERE% - либо заменить на путь в котором искать, либо установить соответствующую переменную, например так:

```
set WHERE=c:\users\
```

%WHAT% - заменить на имя искомого каталога, либо установить переменную как указано выше.

Comment: круто, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такую команду для `cmd`:

```
(for /R "%WHERE%" %A in (.) do @echo %A) | find "\%WHAT%\." | for /f %A in ('more') do @rd /s /q "%A"
```

Где:

%WHERE% - переменная содержащая путь к каталогу где искать цели;

%WHAT% - переменная содержащее полное имя папки, т.е. содержимое между двумя обратными слэшами в пути.

Вместо переменных можно использовать литералы, конечно.

Пояснения:

Группа команд состоит из трёх частей разделённых прямой чертой (|):

1. рекурсивный обход базового каталога с выводом путей
2. поиск имени целевого каталога в конце пути, свидетельствующее о необходимости его обработки
3. обработка списка подходящих путей, полученном на втором шаге. В данном случае, вызов команды удаления.

Для отладки можно использовать следующую команду, которая выведет список папок для удаления:

```
(for /R "%WHERE%" %A in (.) do @echo %A) | find "\%WHAT%\." | for /f %A in ('more') do @echo # %A
```

Для использования команды в пакетном файле необходимо заменить `%A` на `%%A`.

Comment: а что такое more ? я подставил, что-то не удаляет

Comment: @RakzinRoman  `more` позволяет читать канал переданный в последнюю команду `for`, подробную информацию можно найти в справке, как в командной строке - `more /?`, так и в справочной системе  `Windows` (раньше это был файл `%WINDIR%\Help\ntcmds.chm`). Прежде чем использовать первую команду, нужно проверить на второй, которая выведет список путей, и если всё верно - то можно использовать первую.